# notifyAll in java

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

Is it wrong to use `notifyAll()` inside the loop in a multiple producer-consumer problem in Java?

Here is the code snippet which I am talking about.

```
public void run() {

        while(producer_counter <= 64) {

            synchronized(list) {

                threadId1 = "Producer " + Thread.currentThread().getName();

                //Buffer size is 8
                while(list.size() >= 8) {
                    System.out.println( "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                    System.out.println(threadId1+ " found the buffer is full & waiting for a Consumer to consume.");
                    System.out.println( "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                    try {

                        list.wait();
                        list.notifyAll();
                    }

                    catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(threadId1+ " produced item " + producer_counter);
                //Adding the items produced to the list.
                list.add(producer_counter);
                producer_counter++;
                //Invoking notify
                list.notifyAll();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of notifying threads when you haven't changed anything? There's nothing they need to know about since nothing has changed since they decided to block.

Answer (score 1):

`notifyAll()` is to notify all parties about changes in the state of the synchronized object. The first call, which is after `wait()`, is redundant because no state change happened. This call does not make the program wrong, but only causes waste of CPU cycles: when the buffer is full, `notifyAll()` is called and all other threads, waiting for the buffer's availability, go to processor only to call `notifyAll()` again and then call `wait()`. As a result, one processor in your machine will be always busy making unnecessary work.

BTW, you should not catch `InterruptedException` (or any other exception) if you don't know why it happened and what to do about it. If, like here, you cannot write `public void run() throws InterruptedException`, then write

```
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ie);
}
```

Instead of `RuntimeException`, better declare your own unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use list.notifyAll() in while loop.After adding the items produced to the list list.add(producer_counter) you can use notify all.

```
            // producer thread waits while list is full
            while (list.size() >= 8){
                list.wait();
            }

            // to insert the jobs in the list and plus 1 the counter
            list.add(producer_counter);
            producer_counter++;

            // notifies the consumer threads that now it can start 
           //consuming
            list.notifyAll();
```

Comment: You should explain *why* the asker should not use `notifyAll` in the loop.